# Using the Can Shrink option for Currency

Tags: ms-access, report

I am creating a report in Microsoft Access 2019.

Using the code: `=IIf(Trim(Nz([TextBox],""))="","","TextBox")`, I have been able to use the can shrink option to save space, and make the report easier to read.  Using this and similar codes, I have been able to shrink text boxes, dates, and check boxes.

I am having trouble with currency though.  Since the currency boxes are already filled as $0.00, I can't use the code above.

When I tried these two codes: `=IIf(Trim(Nz([Base Cost],"$0.00"))="","","Base Cost")` or `=IIf(Trim(Nz([Base Cost],""))="$0.00","","Base Cost")` I got an error saying "The control has a reference to itself"

Along the same lines, how would I code the unbound box label for the Currency if I want it to shrink.

In Essence: I have two boxes:  Base Cost and $0.00.  I'm having trouble figuring out an If/Then statement for the currency to display ONLY if it has value greater than 0.  Then how would I code the Base Cost label to display ONLY if the currency if greater than 0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I got an error saying "The control has a reference to itself"

warns you, that the control (textbox) has the same name as the bound field (if you use add existing fields, they are named equal) what only is valid, if control is directly bound to the field.

You should always rename those controls, to prevent side-effects (like the circular-reference).

Empty controls can be made invible, instead of shrinking. To format by condition, use conditional.formatting (no visible property, but setting background and textcolor to to forms color hides too).
To check for`= ""`as condition only catches empty fields. Check the unformated value!

---

```
Trim(Nz([Base Cost],""))="$0.00"
```

can't get true, as`[Base Cost]`is empty or 0. It just displays $0.00, because of formatting!

---

```
Nz([Base Cost],0)) > 0
```

Sets`[Base Cost]`to zero if empty and then compares if greater zero.

Comment: Thanks!!  This has helped me some, but not entirely.  I am still having trouble getting the text to hide.

Comment: `=IIf(Nz([Base Cost],0) > 0,[Base Cost],"")`doesn't work? Maybe formated in query or table? If you put cursor in textbox it still shows formated?